# node.js promise doesn't resolve inside if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Looking for some help with promises, why will resolve not work inside this if statement?

```
async getTrades() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (this.exchange === 'GDAX') {
            resolve('fake')
            console.log('inside GDAX')
        }
    }.bind(this))
}
```

When I put the resolve outside the if statement (before or after), it works.  And the `console.log('inside GDAX')` does fire, so `this.exchange ==='GDAX'` returns true.

Here is the function that calls it:

```
getHistoricalPortfolioReturn() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var exchange_trades_calls = []
        for (var exchange_account in this.exchange_accounts) {
            if (this.exchange_accounts.hasOwnProperty(exchange_account)) {
                exchange_trades_calls.push(this.exchange_accounts[exchange_account].getTrades())
            }
        }
        Promise.all(exchange_trades_calls)
        .then(function (trades) {
            console.log('resolved')
            console.log('trades: ' + trades)
            resolve(trades)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error('error: ' + error)
        })
    }.bind(this))
}
```

Comment: I think you just need to swap the order of `resolve('fake')` and `console.log`

Comment: i tried that, and tried removing console.log and nothing happens!  I'm pulling my hair out it's probably something simple

Comment: How do you know it's not resolving? Have you chained it with `then`?

Comment: @Li357 just posted the function that calls it.  It resolves if I put the `resolve` function outside the if statement, but I wouldn't think that would matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an `async` function. You do not have to return a promise as it will be automatically wrapped in a promise.

```
async getTrades() {
    if(this.exchange === 'GDAX')  return "fake";
}
```

tldr: You are resolving the incorrect promise.